# Route websites with separate hosts to main domain and subdiretory

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

I have two websites I inherited for one organization: *example.com* and *sub.example.com*. The main website is through a hosting provider that only allows access via their WYSIWYG editor. The subdomain site is WordPress, hosted with a different provider.

The business wants to move *sub.example.com* to *example.com/dir*. The host for *example.com* has an interface for 301 redirects, but no direct edits to htaccess or other configs. The host for *sub.example.com* allows edits to htaccess and some config files, but no direct access to the server. Is there a way for me to set up routing for this that would meet the business requirements without changing hosts?

Ultimately, I will be consolidating everything to a single LAMP stack on Google Cloud. The goal right now is to make the change quickly (or tell leadership it's currently an unrealistic goal) as the previous admin said they'd do it and never did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without changing the provider of your main site or getting additional resources and using hacks (I'm thinking of a load balancer/reverse proxy)

Comment: After a bit of reading, I'm going the load balancer route. Thanks!